# How to auto-save a file every 1 second in vim?

Tags: vim, autosave

I don't want to know about why you should not auto-save or there is swap file etc or whatever reason to not auto-save.

I simply want to auto-save the current working file to save in every 1 second in vim.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: For 2021 readers: If you're using Coc.nvim too please read my answer. I'm a Vim expert.

Comment: Another plugin: https://github.com/907th/vim-auto-save ■ note that most solutions below will create weird entries in the undo history. There seems to be no good solution, refer to https://github.com/907th/vim-auto-save/issues/53 -- although for my purpose (recompile Typst as you type in vim) I don't actually need it to write to the current file so I make it write to another file instead.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/74/is-it-possible-to-make-vim-auto-save-files/79#79 suggests `autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * update`.

Answer (score 78):

This saves the buffer whenever text is changed. (Vim 7.4)

`autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer> silent write`

Comment: Thumb up for elegance and simplicity! Worked like a breeze! [One needs to put this in his `_vimrc`.]

Comment: This doesn't literally solve the problem posed, but it seems a really good substitute. Can this be marked as the solution?

Comment: `autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI * silent write` works for any buffer.

Comment: this breaks editing of files opened in read-only mode

Comment: Have a look at [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60095826/3383640).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814520/2641825 says that "`:update` is better suited than `:write`, because it only actually saves when there are unpersisted updates."

Comment: I'm new to VIM. I don't understand where to enter this command. A bit more detail in this post would be very  useful for beginners

Answer (score 10):

When you start reading a file, set a buffer variable to the current time:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile * let b:save_time = localtime()
```

Set an event to check if enough time has elapsed since the last save and update if not:

```
au CursorHold * call UpdateFile()
```

Set the auto-save period, in seconds:

```
let g:autosave_time = 1
```

Define a function to save the file if needed:

```
" save if needed / update the save_time after the save
function! UpdateFile()
  if((localtime() - b:save_time) >= g:autosave_time)
      update
      let b:save_time = localtime()
  else
      " just debugging info
      echo "[+] ". (localtime() - b:save_time) ." seconds have elapsed so far."
  endif
endfunction
```

Then, to reset the save time explicitly:

```
au BufWritePre * let b:save_time = localtime()
```

I have not tested the above on vim 7.0 and later. Also, the CursorHold event is unlikely to be enough for such a small auto-save period (it also doesn't trigger when recording) - maybe you should also call `UpdateFile()` on CursorMoved as well.

Also, consider using swap files. By default a swap file is writen to after either 200 characters typed or 4 seconds of inactivity. Recovery from swap is quite simple and maybe more reliable, in case something goes wrong.

Comment: It seems that this feature is already planned for next versions of Vim (on Vim 7.3 `:help autosave` displays from `todo.txt`).

For the moment I believe there are no suitable autocmd/event to write a vimscript to perform save for every second. But solution proposed by Michael should work for most of cases, because even if it doesn't perform saves when cursor is not moved, it is not very likely that you will perform any changes without moving the cursor.

Comment: In vim 7.4, the built-in autosave feature is still listed under improvements to be added in future versions.

Answer (score 4):

### For Readers in 2021 and You're using CoC.nvim Plugin

Use this which is compatible to Coc.nvim:

```
autocmd InsertLeave * if &readonly==0 && filereadable(bufname('%')) \
                       | silent update | endif
```

The accepted answer will cause the autocompletion fails.

Peace.

---

Showing some UI to prove I love (neo)Vim(-nightly): (Clickable, many others see my profile intro.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [vim-workspace](https://github.com/thaerkh/vim-workspace) plugin has a fairly customizable auto-save feature that may suit your needs (with autoread so you get last writer wins behaviour).
You can set it to always autosave (by default, it only autosaves while in a workspace session) and set your updatetime accordingly.

```
let g:workspace_autosave_always = 1
updatetime=1000
```