# How do I repeat any command on regular interval in vim?

Tags: vim, save, autosave

Actually I want to autosave my current file, `:w` command writes the file so I thought that when I will repeat this command at regular interval (say each 30secs.) I will achieve what I want. But how can I do so?

Comment: Crap. I had it setup once, but I scraped it before I put my vimrc under version control. It used updatetime, I think. But it created problems of its own that made autosave not worth it for me. Now I have `inoremap <Esc> <Esc>:w<CR>` which does what I need and not more.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991638/how-to-auto-save-a-file-every-1-second-in-vim?rq=1

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38183/25982. Use this to run something every X milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into `:help autosave`

Comment: That directs you to todo.txt; as of Vim 7.3.584, it's not implemented yet. Volunteers welcome :-)

Comment: Autosave is available in VIM 7.3.

Answer (score 4):

Vimscript itself is single-threaded; you cannot regularly execute a command per se. The closest to a periodic trigger are autocmds, especially the `CursorHold` event, which fires after no key has been pressed for `'updatetime'`, typically 4 seconds.

Another interesting event for auto-saving is `FocusLost`, but that one may not be triggered in the terminal, just in GVIM.

With it, something like this can be defined:

```
autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI <buffer> silent! write
```

Comment: I googled around for this stuff a bit last night and there are some promising results (including a few specifically for auto-saving) that all use this `CursorHold` approach.