# Auto-save in VIM as you type

Tags: vim

As the question title mentions. I'm looking to automatically get the file saved as I type in VIM (insert mode).

Is this possible? How to achieve it?

Comment: Have you checked this? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto-save_current_buffer_periodically

Comment: This might also be helpful: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Auto_save_files_when_focus_is_lost

Comment: For people using `autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * update` from wikia, note that this has problems with plugins like Telescope that open custom dialogs as the script will attempt to save the dialog. Use `*.*` instead of `*` to exclude non-file buffers.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/79/6671 suggests `autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * update`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use AutoSave plugin to perform that:

https://github.com/907th/vim-auto-save

Please notice that AutoSave is disabled by default, run `:AutoSaveToggle` to enable/disable it.

Comment: This simply doesn't work. After I enable the autosave, and do some changes to the file, the file is not updated.

Comment: Agreed with @omar. When I type :AutoSaveToggle I get an error that it doesn't exist, when I type :run AutoSaveToggle it does nothing.

Comment: After further investigation, it I think this is a communication issue. The first line of this answer about using :AutoSaverToggle REQUIRES the plugin vim auto save to work. This was not my interpretation of the message from Jayram, especially because of the second line, which implies that it is a native VIM command and in addendum you could also use the plugin. However, the plugin is required for this command.

Comment: @Brettins Yes, `:AutoSaveToggle` is a part of the `AutoSave` plugin. It is not a native Vim command!

Comment: Finally found how to install this plugin: need to config the plugin in the .vimrc, and then run `:PluginInstall` without specifying any plugin name.

Answer (score 43):

I recommend to save the buffer whenever text is changed:

```
autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer> silent write
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27387138/4217744). It works for me.

**Note** *(thanks to @Kevin)*: Unfortunately, it will result in errors if you open vim without opening a file because vim will try to save the text you type but won't have where.

Comment: This is the literal solution. No need to make things complex with plugins.

Comment: This will result in errors if you open vim without opening a file.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Kevin for your important comment!

Comment: @simhumileco a way around this could be to specify the buffer type. For example `autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI *.md silent write`

Comment: As noted by @eric you can check if the buffer is readonly, but this appears to work for verifying that it is backed by a file: `au TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer> if &readonly == 0 && filereadable(bufname('%')) | silent write | endif`

Comment: Instead of `TextChanged`, you can use the `updatetime` & `CursorHold` combination (file will be saved updatetime ms after the cursor stops moving).
Put `set updatetime=500` and `au CursorHold,CursorHoldI <buffer> if &readonly == 0 && filereadable(bufname('%')) | silent write | endif` into your `vimrc`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34814520/2641825 says that "`:update` is better suited than `:write`, because it only actually saves when there are unpersisted updates."

Answer (score 5):

This will handle read-only buffers (like netrw) and undetected filetypes. Using TextChangedI instead of InsertLeave seems to cause a write for every character typed in insert mode, which may or may not be what you want.

```
augroup autosave
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufRead * if &filetype == "" | setlocal ft=text | endif
    autocmd FileType * autocmd TextChanged,InsertLeave <buffer> if &readonly == 0 | silent write | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: Could you explain each line of your code?

Comment: line 2: clear all autocmds in this group
line 3: if the filetype is unset, set it to "text"
line 4: When leaving insert, and the text changed, and the file is writable, save the file

Answer (score 2):

There is no native support for auto-saving in Vim.
But you can use [vim-auto-save](https://github.com/907th/vim-auto-save) plugin to perform that.

This plugin auto-saves in normal mode only by default, but there is [a section in it's README](https://github.com/907th/vim-auto-save#events) which describes how to configure the plugin to save in insert mode too. *Hint: you should configure the plugin to auto-save on `CursorHoldI` and/or `TextChangedI` Vim events.*

Please, refer to the plugin documentation on how to install and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if someone mentioned this.
Autosave Per File Type

( in this case it is for a Markdown *.md file)

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.md :autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer> silent write
```

This will write the contents of the file the moment they are modified but only for Markdown (*.md) files.

Answer (score 0):

907th/vim-auto-save auto saves file. But if your .vimrc depends on write event, then it could have issue.

Recently, I notice https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-autosave, which saves files to a backup dir, which sounds promising if your .vimrc depends on write event.

Answer (score 0):

Using a function with logic to handle read only buffers and empty buffers in tandem with a autocommand works pretty well:

```
" auto save file when it is modified
augroup auto_save
  autocmd!
  " call save function
  autocmd BufModifiedSet * call AutoSave()
augroup end

" save function that is called when buffer is modified
function AutoSave()
  if (bufname() != "" && &buftype == "" && &filetype != "" && &readonly == 0)
    silent write
  " prevent empty, readonly, etc... buffers from being saved
  else
  endif
endfunction
```

The autogroup `auto_save` contains an autocommand that calls `AutoSave()`. It is executed whenever the current buffer is modified(see `:help BufModifiedSet`). The `AutoSave()` function writes the buffer only if it is writeable, it is not blank, and it(the buffer) has a file type.