# Use <Esc> key to save file with one key press in Insert mode or Normal mode

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I try to map my <Esc> key to save file with **one key press only**.

In Normal Mode, it works so far.

```
map <Esc> :w <CR>
```

But I have trouble to map it in Insert mode, 
I tried the following command, but it does't work

```
map <Esc> <Esc>[ :w <CR>
```

By the way, I only want **One Key Press only**.

Please give me some suggestions, or if you know any good key to save file with **One press** in Vim

Comment: Those spaces within your mappings are not needed and actually probably interfering with what you're trying to do, as they will be executed as a command (in normal mode, space moves the cursor forward by one position). Also what's that "[ " trying to do in your second mapping?

Answer (score 13):

Note that mapping `<Esc>`, especially in insert mode, is not recommended. Most special keys (like cursor and function keys) are sent as *Escape sequences* by the terminal. An alternative would be hooking into the `InsertLeave` event:

```
:autocmd InsertLeave * silent! update
```

`:update` is better suited than `:write`, because it only actually saves when there are unpersisted updates. `:silent!` suppresses errors when the buffer hasn't been named, etc.

Comment: Nice suggestion, Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You keep emphasizing **One press** as if it was the most important part of your problem but the important part is **Insert mode**.

`:map` is a recursive mapping command for *normal*, *visual* and *operator-pending* modes.

You are supposed to use `:imap` — or its non-recursive friend `:inoremap` — for insert mode:

```
:inoremap <Esc> <Esc>:w<CR>
```

**For what it's worth, I recommend Ingo's solution.**

Answer (score 0):

```
augroup AUTOSAVE
  au!
  autocmd InsertLeave,TextChanged,FocusLost * silent! update
augroup END
```

To autosave on *InsertLeave*, *TextChanged* and *FocusLost* events