# Use Autosave in Vim using no plugin?

Tags: vim

How to autosave in Vim using no plugin?

I have found the following post:

[Auto-save in VIM as you type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365324/auto-save-in-vim-as-you-type)

which gives the following answer:

```
autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI <buffer> silent write
```

which works perfectly except that when I put that in my .vimrc it doesn't work, so how can I put that line in my .vimrc such that it works everytime I open Vim ?

**EDIT**: It seems putting that line in .vimrc works WHEN I DON'T USE A SESSION !

So I will rephrase my question:

How can I get the above work in combination with mksession to open preconfigured session in Vim using vim -S ?

Comment: you problem cannot be reproduced. with the line in vimrc, autosave works.

Comment: You need `*` instead of `<buffer>`, but have a look at the autowrite option

Comment: Be aware that vim creates swapfiles which would allow you to restore unsaved changes. This may or may not solve your usecase without a hard autosave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments by `D. Ben Knoble`, you need to use `*` instead of `<buffer>`:

```
autocmd TextChanged,TextChangedI * silent write
```