# Vim automatic scroll buffer

Tags: vim, buffer, autoscroll

I'm trying to do something very simple:

I have two buffers in Vim, one with source code (B1), another one with a text file `a.txt` (B2). The source code in B1 is run with a custom shortcut in Vim, filling `a.txt` with text. I want Vim to automatically scroll B2 every time it updates, even if my cursor is in B1. So, I just want that the buffer B2 to behave the way `tail -f` does.

Doing this with ConqueTerm is not an option, since buffer B2 can be a preview buffer from other plugin.

Answer (score 2):

In general, vim events fire in response to user input. They don't just run continuously in the background.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991638/how-to-auto-save-a-file-every-1-second-in-vim) details some tricks you could repurpose to write some customization code to reload your "tail -f" buffer and scroll to the bottom periodically.

Rather than trying to do this all in vim, here is a different proposal that would achieve a similar effect using [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) (one terminal area with vim editing a file `file1`, another running `tail -f` against a different file `file2`):

- download/install [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) (perhaps `apt-get install screen`)
- run `screen`
- run `vim file1`
- type `Ctrl-A S` to split the terminal down the middle horizontally (or, in recent versions of `screen`, `Ctrl-A |` to split it down the middle vertically)
- type `Ctrl-A Tab` to switch to the other side of the split
- type `Ctrl-A c` to start a new terminal on this side
- run `tail -f file2`

Now one side of the split shows `vim file1` and the other side shows `tail -f file2`. Here's an image of the result.

[image: Here's an image of me using <code>vim</code> and <code>gnu screen</code>.]

Comment: Hello Russell, thanks for the answer, but screen is not a option. As i say, the buffer B2 can be a preview buffer ( and on my most important case it is). The solution ideia is to be inside vim, not outside. Your solution works for an external file acting like a log, and actually it doesn't need screen, just a simple terminal window splitted, new tab, or using multiplexers (screen or tmux). I will keep looking for the solution in an vim style/lang.

Answer (score 1):

This command moves to the window containing `a.txt`, reloads it (`edit`), moves to the end (`+$`) and then jumps back to the previous window. You can add it to the shortcut that runs your source code to get `a.txt` to update whenever the code is run.

`:exe bufwinnr("a.txt") . "wincmd w" | edit +$ | exe winnr("#") . "wincmd w"`

Remember to escape the bars (`\|`) and add a `<CR>` at the end if you use this in a mapping.

This will require your shortcut to run the code in foreground, and Vim will be unresponsive till it is done (unless you press Ctrl-C). If you want Vim to reload `a.txt` automatically whenever it is changed (thus bypassing the need for running the code in foreground), you will need an external mechanism for file change detection (such as `inotifywait` on Linux). As far as I know, Vim only checks for external changes (with `autoread`) when you move the cursor to that window.