# Spawn and follow a process output in VIM

Tags: vim

A mate at work was showing me his emacs-fu with `comint` mode, and showed me something quite interesting.

He was able to spawn a process and watch the output in the buffer window, with all of the benefits of doing this in an editor, such as being to search and replace in the window while the process is running.

I know how to spawn a process and capture the output when it's finished, but was wondering if you can do it while it's running from vim- e.g for a long running compile, you can trace the output and search it while the process is still running.

Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785389/using-vim-as-a-logfile-viewer/785412) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867721/tail-like-functionality-for-gvim). But a good question nontheless.

Comment: Somewhat similar question [Vim automatic scroll buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17751700).

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for [Conque](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771).

```
:ConqueTerm <command>
:ConqueTermSplit <command>
:ConqueTermVSplit <command>
:ConqueTermTab <command>
```

`<command>` can be for example a bash shell or whatever you want.

[image]