# How to autosave all files periodicatlly in Vim?

Tags: vim

I was using gedit for a while and now I am using vim . There was a nice option of autosave in gedit . I want to know if there is an option of autosaving in vim. I want to save my codes which I am writing after every 1 minute because of the disruption of electricity.

Comment: Same for current file only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991638/how-to-auto-save-a-file-every-1-second-in-vim

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [vim-auto-save script](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vim-auto-save) to save files every time their buffers are modified.